# How to set up a listener for a variable in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, listener, kotlin-delegate

How to I set up an interface listener for detecting a variable change in Kotlin. I successful implemented the following in Java, but am running into issues doing it in Kotlin:

Interface:

```
public interface InterfaceRefreshList
    {
    public void refreshListRequest();
    }
```

Class containing listener:

```
public class SignalChange
    {
    private static boolean refreshListSwitch;
    private static List<InterfaceRefreshList> refreshListListeners = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void setRefreshList(boolean value)
    {
    refreshListSwitch = value;
    for(InterfaceRefreshList l : refreshListListeners)
        l.refreshListRequest();
    }
    public static void addRefreshListListener(InterfaceRefreshList l)
        {
        refreshListListeners.add(l);
        }
    }
```

Class where listener is listening:

```
public class FragmentBrowse extends Fragment
{
    public FragmentBrowse() /// Constructor
        {
        SignalChange.addRefreshListListener(() -> refreshList());
        }
    refreshList()
    {
    // do something
    }
}
```

To signal a change:

```
SignalChange.setRefreshList(true);
```

I can set up the interface and the signal class:

```
class SignalChange
{
    private var refreshListSwitch: Boolean = false
    var setSwitch: Boolean
        get() = refreshListSwitch
        set(value)
        {
            refreshListSwitch = value
        }

    private var refreshListListeners = ArrayList<InterfaceRefreshPersonsList>()
    fun sendRefreshSignal()
    {
        for(l in refreshListListeners) l.refreshPersonsList()
    }

    fun addRefreshListListener(l: InterfaceRefreshPersonsList)
    {
        refreshListListeners.add(l)
    }

}
```

But I cannot setup the listener in the FragmentBrowse class. The fragment class doesn't allow constructors.

Comment: Which issues are you running into? Why don't you simply run the Java to Kotlin converter on your Java code?

Comment: The converter doesn't simply work like that. For example, the static setter for the private variable I had to do: private var refreshListSwitch: Boolean = false
 var setSwitch: Boolean
  get() = refreshListSwitch
  set(value)
  {
   refreshListSwitch = value
  }

Comment: Why did you have to do that? This looks entirely unnecessary. Anyway, you didn't answer what issues specifically you ran into with your Kotlin code.

Comment: See edited code

Comment: The code for adding a listener needs to be placed in an [initializer block](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors). The built-in Java to Kotlin converter in IntelliJ IDEA is capable of performing this conversion automatically.

Comment: I already tried in init block and added instance of SignalChange: signalChange = SignalChange(), but the following does not convert: signalChange.addRefreshListListener(() -> refreshList());

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use built-in Kotlin delegates, for example:

```
object SignalChange {
    var refreshListListeners = ArrayList<InterfaceRefreshList>()

    // fires off every time value of the property changes
    var property1: String by Delegates.observable("initial value") { property, oldValue, newValue ->
        // do your stuff here
        refreshListListeners.forEach { 
            it.refreshListRequest()
        }
    }
}

interface InterfaceRefreshList {
    fun refreshListRequest()
}
```

Add listeners like this:

```
SignalChange.refreshListListeners.add(object : InterfaceRefreshList {
    override fun refreshListRequest() {
        refreshList()
    }
})
```

**OR**

Intead of interface you can use **lambda**:

```
object SignalChange {
    var refreshListListeners = ArrayList<() -> Unit>()

    // fires off every time value of the property changes
    var property1: String by Delegates.observable("initial value") { property, oldValue, newValue ->
        // do your stuff here
        refreshListListeners.forEach {
            it()
        }
    }
}
```

And to add listener just call:

```
SignalChange.refreshListListeners.add(::refreshList)
//or
SignalChange.refreshListListeners.add { refreshList() }

fun refreshList() {

}
```

Comment: With the posted Java code I was able to signal a change from anywhere in the program. Can the Delegates.observable do that?

Comment: I edited my answer. When you set value to `property1` Delegates.observable fires off and invokes `refreshListRequest()` on each listener.

Comment: This seems the same as fun sendRefreshSignal() for(l in refreshListListeners) l.refreshPersonsList() but the issue I am having is how to invoke: fun addRefreshListListener(l: InterfaceRefreshPersonsList) refreshListListeners.add(l) from the FragmentBrowse class

Comment: it seems you need implement `SignalChange` as `Singleton`. And then you will be able to add listeners like this. I've edited my answer, now `SignalChange ` is a `Singleton`

Comment: You gave us 2 answers which is great. Is one better than the other?

Answer (score 13):

The **simple** way to Listen to variable in **KOTLIN**

```
private var myVariableName by Delegates.observable(0) { property, oldValue, newValue ->
             Log.d(TAG,"New Value $newValue")
             Log.d(TAG,"Old Value $oldValue")
        }
```

for more info read https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/

Comment: Thank you. How do you assign a type for myVariableName ? I tried ```myVariableName: String by Delegates....``` and it does not work

Comment: Oh, I get it. Assigning 0 as the initial value automatically makes myVariableName as an Int. So we should do ```myVariableName by Delegates.observable("Initial Text")``` for a String